# MVC4 Action only triggers while debugging locally

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an action I use to reset the password for my users:

```
public class Password : Controller{
  public ActionResult Reset(string id)
  {
    //...
  }

}
```

The **id** is actually the **encrypted email** address provided by the user when asked which email address the password recovery is for.

So, if I click on the "Forgot Password?" link, and provide the email address user@domain.com the resulting url sent to the user's email would be something like:

> http://www.myapp.com/admin/password/reset/euPdxABQEgE0JDuv6OHSLnk1QBYf73YseBUZwR9+MJA=

That would be routed to the Reset action on the Password controller included above.
This is working fine while I'm debugging the app locally.
This is **NOT** working on my test server; I'm getting a 404 instead.

**Interesting facts:**

1. If I remove the Id from the url
   http://www.myapp.com/admin/password/reset/ I get redirected to the
   index action of the password controller with the proper message
   "Invalid link" as expected.
2. I if include any other string in the id (ie: http://www.myapp.com/admin/password/reset/abc123) I get redirected as expected; as described in 1).

So it seems that this is somehow related with the anatomy of the id I'm passing around. I tried url encoding it but that didn't work.

This is the route definition for the Admin Area:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
   context.MapRoute(
      "Admin_default",
      "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
}
```

The main routes are the default ones.

Any ideas?

Comment: Side note: Consider encrypting a time stamp + the user email so you can expire the link.

Comment: Consider urlEncoding the encrypted text to pass as parameter

Comment: @MikeSmithDev nice advice, I'm currently not expiring the links but I will do what you are recommending here.

Comment: @MillerKoijam yes, I found that is necessary too after following the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that this is because of the `+` sign in the path portion of your url. You may take a look at the [`following blog post`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) in which Scott Hanselman explains the difficulties that you will encounter by attempting to pass such special characters in the path portion.

I will quote only his conclusion:

> After ALL this effort to get crazy stuff in the Request Path, it's
>   worth mentioning that simply keeping the values as a part of the Query
>   String (remember WAY back at the beginning of this post?) is easier,
>   cleaner, more flexible, and more secure.

So simply drop that and use the following url:

```
http://www.myapp.com/admin/password/reset?id=euPdxABQEgE0JDuv6OHSLnk1QBYf73YseBUZwR9%2BMJA%3D
```

Notice how I url encoded the string which is what you should be doing when passing parameters as query string values in an url.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I tried reset?id=... and it works; however the content of the id has to be UrlEncoded too.
Thanks a ton!